# Iterating through properties of an object as well as elements in its embedded arrays to render html elements for each

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with a few top-level properties and one embedded array. I'm attempting to render an `html` element for each `key/value` pair as well as for each item in the array, but when it gets to the array, it just combines its elements into a single string.

I altered the logic to behave differently for when the value is not a string (so when it is type `object`), however the code does not render anything for that item.

```
//challenge.js

function Challenge(status, activeRange, position, college, teams) {
    this.status = status;
    this.activeRange = activeRange;
    this.position = position;
    this.college = college;
    this.teams = teams;
}

const challenge1 = new Challenge("Active","2000-2013","RB","Alabama",["Eagels", "Dolphins"]);

module.exports = challenge1;

//App.js

const challenge1 = require('./models/challenge.js');

var challengeProperties = Object.keys(challenge1).map(function(key){
  if (typeof challenge1[key] == "string")
  return <p value={key}>{key}: {challenge1[key]}</p>
  else
  challenge1.teams.forEach(function(item) {
  return <p>bad</p>
    }
  )
}
)

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        {challengeProperties}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It won't render because you are not returning anything from else condition...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not returning anything from else part

> By default `forEach` returns `undefined`

Use `Array.map` instead

```
var challengeProperties = Object.keys(challenge1).map(function (key, index) {
  if (typeof challenge1[key] === "string"){
    return (
      <p key={index} value={key}>
        {key}: {challenge1[key]}
      </p>
    );
  }
  else{ // should return here
    return challenge1.teams.map(function (item, index) { //use map
      return (
        <p key={index}>
          {key}:{item}
        </p>
      );
    });
  }
});
```